# How can I stop Magento from appending SKU?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, products, sku

So I have a bunch of products with custom options and I would like to stop Magento from appending those other SKUS for these orders.

This is how it shows: SKU1-CUSTOMOPTION1SKU-CUSTOMOPTION2SKU

How can I get it to only show the main products SKU? SKU1

```
  public function getSku($product)
    {
        $sku = $product->getData('sku');
        if ($product->getCustomOption('option_ids')) {
            $sku = $this->getOptionSku($product, $sku);
        }
        return $sku;
    }

    /**
     * Default action to get sku of product with option
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product Product with Custom Options
     * @param string $sku Product SKU without option
     * @return string
     */
    public function getOptionSku($product, $sku = '')
    {
        $skuDelimiter = '-';
        if (empty($sku)) {
            $sku = $product->getData('sku');
        }
        $optionIds = $product->getCustomOption('option_ids');
        if ($optionIds) {
            foreach (explode(',', $optionIds->getValue()) as $optionId) {
                $option = $product->getOptionById($optionId);
                if ($option) {
                    $confItemOption = $product->getCustomOption(self::OPTION_PREFIX . $optionId);

                    $group = $option->groupFactory($option->getType())
                        ->setOption($option)
                        ->setListener(new \Magento\Framework\DataObject());

                    $optionSku = $group->getOptionSku($confItemOption->getValue(), $skuDelimiter);
                    if ($optionSku) {
                        $sku .= $skuDelimiter . $optionSku;
                    }

                    if ($group->getListener()->getHasError()) {
                        $product->setHasError(true)->setMessage($group->getListener()->getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $sku;
    }
```

Comment: Hello @DevAnd, below solution worked for you ? Or do you need further help ?

Answer (score 0):

If a product having `custom option`, its SKU is created on the fly.
If you look at file.

```
MagentoRoot\vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType.php
```

You will find a function `getOptionSku`, which is responsible for creating SKU.

If you want to remove custom option SKU to main product's SKU, You can change to

**$sku**

From

**$sku .= $skuDelimiter . $optionSku;**

Where

```
$sku = SKU of product
$skuDelimiter = -
$optionSku = SKU of custom option of product
```

You can change as per your requirement.

**Note:** Never edit core files, you need a proper Model overriding. For test purpose you can check by putting `die` below this sku generation code and add a product from front.

Comment: I uploaded the code you mentioned can you see what I need to change? A little confused. Also how can I do this without changing magento core files?

Comment: search $sku .= $skuDelimiter . $optionSku; and replace it with $sku.

Comment: Hello @DevAnd,  Did my solution worked for you ?

Answer (score 0):

We've found only simple products append the optional accessory SKU. Have you found a way to have a configurable product append the optional accessory SKU?